# Atom IDE: Control Click to go to declaration, even if another file?

Tags: atom-editor

I just tried switching over to Atom editor, things are going well.

I did use webstorm / Visual studio and they have some great features like Control +Click to go to definition.

I have tried searching for a package but can't seem to find one.

For example Control + Click on a definition would popup a window with all the possibilities

Anyone know anyway of getting this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know they need to build still.

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2256